# Planning a Sharepoint Backup and Recovery Strategy

Tags: sharepoint-server, backup, disaster-recovery

I am a SQL Server DBA, but I am confronted with Sharepoint the very first time. To my understanding I can take a full backup once per day via SQL Server and log backups for example every hour. 
In this scenario Sharepoint full farm backups are not needed, correct?
I want to be able to restore my data with losing a maximum of 1 hour, what strategy is needed? As far as I understand my SQL Server Backups are enough, but in case of a hardware crash I have to setup a new sharepoint and restore from my SQL Backups into it and maybe correct some settings.

Or am I missing something? What do you guys/girls recommend? The server is only used on daytime, so full backups which run over night are no problem.
Also I have enough disk space to save up to 30 Full backups.

I am using Sharepoint 2013 / SQL Server 2014 Standart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are pretty much safe side. We have the same backup strategy, where we run Full backup every week and log shipping for every hour. We are using this since 2007 version. So far no bad luck.

Just keep in mind, cons of SQL backup.

1. their is no granular backup, you have to restore the full content database in order to get the required item.
2. in case of Hardware failure, you have to rebuild the Farm and then create the Services App and web apps...then restore the DBs...it will take longer time but 99% guarantee.

Comment: thank you sir, so you would not recommened to take an additional farm backup once per week for example?

Comment: if you want, you can take it...But for me it redundant work...

Comment: To add to this, we have had similar strategies in the past, another great addition is to perform nightly site collection backups via powershell. This way if a user compromises a site, you don't have to restore the entire content db from backup, you can recover their site. This is extremely effective if you have a flat architecture with many site collections.

Answer (score 0):

In most of cases you should perform a full back-up(farm).
This way you should be able to reconstruct your environment in no time but you need to have a large Disk to do this every week or so.